# PHone and Messaging icons do not show unread message notification or missed call in 4.04

Tags: notifications

I get the sound notification and it shows up in the notification bar, but nothing shows up on the Icon itself for new unread emails or missed phone calls or unread messages. They do show up on the voicemail icon for unheard voice mails. Is there a setting for this. Phone is a ZTE Force from Boost running 4.04.

Thanks

Comment: Would you normally expect to see it on this phone? It's not a standard Android feature but some manufacturers add it. I don't know whether ZTE has added it or not.

Comment: See also [Notification numbers for a lot of apps don't show up](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63712/12442).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem a week ago and I found the solution myself by using "trial and error method" for my Samsung S3 mobile (Android 4.3).

1. Go to *Settings > Application manager*. There you will see turned off application which is named as `BadgeProvider` (in Android 4.3 it is in "turned off" application list but some version hasn't that "turned off" application list and in that situation you will see that application in bottom part of "ALL" application list.
2. So after you got that application you have to tap it and turn it on.

Now your problem should be solved. (Sometimes you have to restart your mobile after this process).

Comment: Yep on my S7 it was in notifications. App icon Badges was turned off. This occurred after the the update. I guess I could get used to it but it is working now. Thank you for the help.